# Movimentar icones em menu em app

Tags: android, imagem, menu, app

No meu projeto, existe um menu, no qual se tem vários ícones pequenos criados através de ImageView, e tenho que deixar esses ícones disponíveis para ser movimentados, semelhante a home do Android. 
Teria algum método para que eu possa fazer está ação?

Comment: Se você utilizar o SDK 14+, você pode usar o [framework de **Drag and Drop**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html), caso contrário terá que implementar a movimentação (não é muito complicado) ou usar alguma lib de terceiros para isso.

Comment: Teria algum exemplo que eu posso implementar, de ambos os casos que você citou @Wakim ?

Comment: Exemplo eu não tenho aqui, e não consigo fazer um no momento, talvez só a noite, mas acho que esse site tem um bom tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html.